# How do I find floor and ceiling rounded dates using lubridate when the dates are in varying orders, but not in date format?

Tags: r, date, lubridate

In R, using `lubridate`, I have dates for records of a species. Some of these dates are records that are specific to day, some are specific to month, and some are specific to year. Many of the dates are recorded in different formats. I have been using `lubridate` to parse these date records.

I want to create a column for 'start_date' and a column for 'end_date', to represent the range of possible days (and therefore uncertainty) for any records that are not specific to a particular day.

My original thought was to use the `floor_date()` function for the start_date column, and `ceiling_date()` function for the end_date column. If a date was already specific to day, then both start and end date would end up the same. If the date was not specific to day, the start and end dates would represent the range.

The problem with this is that `floor_date()` and `ceiling_date()` only work with data that is already formatted into a date format - and if I use `parse_date_time()` from `lubridate` to format into a date format, the date is automatically rounded down. I have not found a way to manually adjust rounding in `parse_date_time()`.

Is there any way for me to get around this?

Some example code to show my problem:

```
library(lubridate)

species <- c("mudkip", "treecko", "torchic", "swampert", "galvantula")
raw_date <- c("5 Jan 2013", "February 2018", "10/2001", "25/12/1984", "2020")

df <- data.frame(species, raw_date)

df$start_date <- floor_date(df$raw_date, unit="day")
df$end_date <- ceiling_date(df$raw_date, unit="day")
```

```
Error in UseMethod("reclass_date", orig) : 
  no applicable method for 'reclass_date' applied to an object of class "character"
In addition: Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

Attempt using parse_date_time for illustration:

```
species <- c("mudkip", "treecko", "torchic", "swampert", "galvantula")
raw_date <- c("5 Jan 2013", "February 2018", "10/2001", "25/12/1984", "2020")

df <- data.frame(species, raw_date)

df$processed_date <- parse_date_time(df$raw_date, orders = c("ymd","dmy", "my", "y"))

df$start_date <- floor_date(df$raw_date, unit="day")
df$end_date <- ceiling_date(df$raw_date, unit="day")

df$start_date[df$species=="torchic"]
#[1] "2001-10-01 UTC"

df$end_date[df$species=="torchic"]
#[1] "2001-10-01 UTC" - I want this to be "2001-10-31 UTC"

df$start_date[df$species=="galvantula"]
#[1] "2020-01-01 UTC"

df$end_date[df$species=="galvantula"]
#[1] "2020-01-01 UTC" - I want this to be "2020-12-31 UTC"
```

Comment: I'd suggest creating a dataframe with separate day, month, year columns together with a function which parses and edits/corrects rows that have missing data in the months or days cols the specific way you want.

Comment: I thought about this as well - but I think that if I want to put the dates in a format which I can then split, I'd need to do something like `parse_date_time()`, which would still round the dates down. So there would be no indicator that the raw data was missing the day or month.

Comment: library(tidyverse)
y <- tribble(
  ~day, ~month, ~year,
  2, 2,1970,
  NA,2,1971,
  NA,NA,1972)
make_date(y$year,y$month,y$day)
fix_dates <- function (year,month=NA,day=NA) {
  if (is.na(day) && is.na(month))   {return(make_datetime(year=year,month=12,day=31))}
  if (is.na(day)) {return(make_datetime(year=year,
                       month=month,                                        day=days_in_month(make_datetime(year=year,month=month,day=1))))}
    
   make_datetime(year,month,day)
      } 
 fix_dates(1970,NA,NA)
 fix_dates(1970,3,NA) 
 fix_dates(1970,2,3)

Comment: This may give a start. Be warned I find purrr/apply functions do not work with fix_dates as defined here and I don't have the time to debug that part.

Comment: Thanks! I don't think this takes into account my main issue, the variation in formatting of dates. In your code, you already know what is a month, what is a day, and what is a year, and whether it is missing - in my case, I have hundreds of thousands of different dates, all in different formats (d-m-y, d/m/y, y-m-d etc). So the issue if I was splitting into a day/month/year column is not how to deal with the dates once split - it is how to split them consistently in the first place, without, for example, a year being marked as a day due to a ymd format compared to a dmy format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE WITH SOLUTION:

I have solved this problem myself, using `parse_date_time()` and the fact that, if a date is not in a pre-defined order, `parse_date_time()` fails and leaves behind an `NA`. I create a dataframe that I then use to figure out what format the date is in, and then create the end_date column based on the format.

I am aware that `lubridate` also features the function `guess_formats()`, but this is less helpful because the function outputs many possible formats.

Code below:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

#Create dataframe

species <- c("mudkip", "treecko", "torchic", "swampert", "galvantula", "volcarona", "joltik")
raw_date <- c("5 Jan 2013", "February 2018", "10/2001", "25/12/1984", "2020", "2012-03-12", "not a date")

# Added Volcarona to my species to have an example in which the year is first in the date format
# Added Joltik to represent a species in which the date is blank or otherwise unreadable

df <- data.frame(species, raw_date)

# Create a dataframe for formatting the dataset - you can just add these columns to the main dataframe, but I found this neater
date_formatting <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=5, nrow=length(df$raw_date)))
names(date_formatting) <- c("raw_date", "ymd","dmy", "my", "y")
date_formatting$raw_date <- df$raw_date
date_formatting$ymd <- parse_date_time(date_formatting$raw_date, orders = c("ymd"))
date_formatting$dmy <- parse_date_time(date_formatting$raw_date, orders = c("dmy"))
date_formatting$my <- parse_date_time(date_formatting$raw_date, orders = c("my"))
date_formatting$y <- parse_date_time(date_formatting$raw_date, orders = c("y"))
# You can use other date formats based on your needs.

# Find what the date format is based on what did and didn't worked
date_formatting <- date_formatting %>%
  mutate(format = case_when(
    !is.na(ymd) ~ "ymd",
    !is.na(dmy) ~ "dmy",
    !is.na(my) ~ "my",
    !is.na(y) ~ "y",
    # TRUE to account for dates that can't be read due to format - could leave blank.
    TRUE ~ "unreadable"
  )) 

df$format <- date_formatting$format

# Start date works as normal regardless of date format
df$start_date <- parse_date_time(df$raw_date, orders = c("ymd","dmy", "my", "y"))

# For end date, calculate values based on format
df <- df %>%
  mutate(end_date = case_when(
  format == "ymd" | format == "dmy" ~ parse_date_time(raw_date, orders = c("ymd","dmy")),
  # When going to the end of the year/month, make sure to use %m+% to account for varying lengths of months/years. 
  # Subtract 1 day to get the last day of that month/year (rather than the first day of the subsequent day/year)
  format == "my" ~ (parse_date_time(raw_date, orders = c("my")) %m+% months(1)) - days(1),
  format == "y" ~ (parse_date_time(raw_date, orders = c("y")) %m+% years(1)) - days(1),
  TRUE ~ NA_real_))
```

I hope this helps any future people with similar issues! If anyone has a more elegant solution I'd love to know.